# Capturing https traffic from Java in Fiddler

Tags: java, fiddler

I am using HTMLUnit and HttpsURLConnection, my program works fine when I don't have the proxy setting set to Fiddler, but when I do set it to Fiddler I get the following message for HTTPS requests

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Host name 'site.com' does not match the certificate subject provided by the peer (CN=*.site.com, O=DO_NOT_TRUST, OU=Created by http://www.fiddler2.com)
```

This used to work for me but now it does not. Any idea how I can get rid of the exception?

I remember a few years ago I had to use the following to make it work, and it was working up untill a few weeks a go. I am not sure if something changed in Fiddler or Java

```
public final class XTrustProvider extends java.security.Provider
{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long   serialVersionUID    = 1L;
    private final static String NAME        = "XTrustJSSE";
    private final static String INFO        = "XTrust JSSE Provider (implements trust factory with truststore validation disabled)";
    private final static double VERSION = 1.0D;

    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
    public XTrustProvider()
    {
        super(NAME, VERSION, INFO);

        AccessController.doPrivileged(new PrivilegedAction()
        {
            public Object run()
            {
                put("TrustManagerFactory." + TrustManagerFactoryImpl.getAlgorithm(), TrustManagerFactoryImpl.class.getName());
                return null;
            }
        });
    }

    public static void install()
    {
        if (Security.getProvider(NAME) == null)
        {
            Security.insertProviderAt(new XTrustProvider(), 2);
            Security.setProperty("ssl.TrustManagerFactory.algorithm", TrustManagerFactoryImpl.getAlgorithm());
        }
    }

    public final static class TrustManagerFactoryImpl extends TrustManagerFactorySpi
    {
        public TrustManagerFactoryImpl()
        {
        }

        public static String getAlgorithm()
        {
            return "XTrust509";
        }

        protected void engineInit(KeyStore keystore) throws KeyStoreException
        {
        }

        protected void engineInit(ManagerFactoryParameters mgrparams) throws InvalidAlgorithmParameterException
        {
            throw new InvalidAlgorithmParameterException(XTrustProvider.NAME + " does not use ManagerFactoryParameters");
        }

        protected TrustManager[] engineGetTrustManagers()
        {
            return new TrustManager[]
            { new X509TrustManager()
            {
                public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers()
                {
                    return null;
                }

                public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType)
                {
                }

                public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType)
                {
                }
            } };
        }
    }
}
```